# How to change days label of kendoDatePicker from su,mo to sun ,mon?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker, kendo-datetimepicker

i using kendoDatePicker and i want to change labels of days at the top of the datepicker content from Su,mo ect to sun, mon.

Comment: You are probably using the culture `en-US`, right? You can change it in the [culture file](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/cultures/kendo.culture.en-US.js#L34) or create your own.

Comment: no i am using culture: "de-DE",

Comment: Doesn't metter, you can edit any culture file.